# Hyperledger Composer: command "composer network start" failing with "Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Suddenly I cannot start my hyperledger composer business network any more ...

```
composer network start --networkName my-network --networkVersion 0.0.45 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw
```

is giving me the following error message:

Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT

I reset docker to factory settings ... but the problem remains.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: have you tried restarting the docker containers? [docker-compose stop and then docker-compose start]  Maybe this can help refer to composer start network issues [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--composer-network-start-issues)

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Request timeout can have 2 main reasons 
1. There is some code in your logic.js, permission.acl or query that is taking too long to resolve , look for any infinite loops or Dynamic queries or any complex permission that you have added. 
Resolution: If you have some previous version which was working try on that slowly bring in your changes to check if any of your changes have caused the network start to run for long.
Alternatively you can also look into the docker logs which is created when you fire network start command and there are chances you found your issue there.

2. In case you are using some VM or low performance machine , there could be also be chances that load of your machine to too much and it is not able to handle so much processing collectively.
   Resolution : Check for any previous docker container or memory extensive processes to make sure there is enough hardware to complete the task in time bound manner.